# Como fazer um Bruteforce em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loop

Estou tentando criar um programa Bruteforce que possa gerar senhas com um tamanho **x** de caracteres. O problema é que eu não consigo desenvolver uma lógica para isso. Veja o meu código abaixo:

```
chars = getAllChars() # Obtém caracteres [A-z 0-9]

password = "pato34" # Senha que deverá ser encontrada

c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6 = "", "", "", "", "", ""

def checks(*chars, show = True):
    global password
    string = ""

    for char in chars:
        string += char

    if show: print(string)
    if string == password: return True

def bruteForce():
    global c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6

    for c1 in chars:
        if checks(*getChars()): return getChars()

        for c2 in chars:
            if checks(*getChars()): return getChars()

            for c3 in chars:
                if checks(*getChars()): return getChars()

                for c4 in chars:
                    if checks(*getChars()): return getChars()

                    for c5 in chars:
                        if checks(*getChars()): return getChars()

                        for c6 in chars:
                            if checks(*getChars()): return getChars()

def getChars():
    return c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6

print(bruteForce())
```

Esse código basicamente tenta todas as combinações possíveis com todas as letras e números até achar uma senha de 6 dígitos. O problema é que se eu quiser fazer um Bruteforce para senhas de 20 dígitos, eu deveria escrever 20 blocos `for`.

Dá para reduzir isso de forma que não precise escrever mais linhas de código para um tamanho maior de senha ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu já dei o meu joinha para o C.Bohok, acima, mas um problema que encontrei é que se a gente incluir um carácter no password (por exemplo: #) que não tem em digits o programa dele vai rodar até atingir o valor máximo de combinações, que eu acho que é igual ao fatorial de (len(digits) = 62), tentando encontrar uma correspondência. Para ver o valor, faça no modo interativo do python3:

> from math import factorial
>
> factorial(62)

Em se tratando de um password a principio nós não sabemos quais são os caracteres que o compõe mas as vezes podemos saber qual é o tamanho máximo dele.

Se me permitirem, abaixo apresento duas funções sendo uma desenvolvida usando instruções básicas do python e outra usando o módulo itertools que permite inclusive criar programas para a loteria.

A função usando itertools é mais rápida.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from itertools import product

chars  = [chr(i) for i in range(97, 123)]
chars += [chr(i) for i in range(65, 91)]
chars += [chr(i) for i in range(48, 58)]

# Ou descomente a linha abaixo para incluir todos os caracteres geralmente usados em um password
#chars  = [chr(i) for i in range(32, 127)]

password = 'gato'
tentativa = 0

def bruteForce_1(chars, password, lenPass):
    tentativa = 0

    for i in product(chars, repeat=lenPass):
        combina = ''.join(i)
        tentativa += 1
    
        if (tentativa % 500000 == 0):
            print('%10i --> %s' % (tentativa, combina))

        if password == combina:
            return('Senha encontrada é "{}", após {} tentativas.'.format(combina, tentativa))

    return ('Senha NÃO encontrada')

def bruteForce_2(chars, password, lenPass, comb_anterior = ''):
    global tentativa

    for LETRA in chars:
        combina = comb_anterior + LETRA
        tentativa += 1
        if (tentativa % 500000 == 0):
            print('%10i --> %s' % (tentativa, combina))

        if password == combina:
            print('Senha encontrada é "{}", após {} tentativas.'.format(combina, tentativa))
            #return 'ok'
            exit()

        elif (lenPass != 1):
            # E aqui a chamada da recursividade
            bruteForce_2(chars, password, lenPass-1, combina)

print(bruteForce_1(chars, password, lenPass=4))
print('*' * 60 + '\n')

print(bruteForce_2(chars, password, len(password)))
print('*' * 60 + '\n')

print(bruteForce_2(chars, 'cabo', 4))
print('*' * 60 + '\n')

print(bruteForce_2(chars, 'cabo', 5))

# Fim
```

Experimentem mudar os parâmetros passados para as funções.

Bom... para resumir as possibilidades são muitas...

E seja feliz.